# Reading feature from a GML3 content-string

Tags: gml

How can I show the geometries from a GML3 file? **Nothing is shown.**

This question is DIFFERENT from [Show GML on map (using an example GML file)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/378609/openlayers-show-gml-on-map-using-an-example-gml-file).

The other project was to get a strange GML2 file visible on the map.

In my Angular project, I first set the specific projection.

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:28992", "+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000  +ellps=bessel  +towgs84=565.040,49.910,465.840,-0.40939,0.35971,-1.86849,4.0772 +units=m +no_defs");
register(proj4)
this.dutchProjection = GetProjection('EPSG:28992');
```

This is how I read the GML file (without errors):

```
this.gmlFeatures = new GML3().readFeatures(this.fileText, {
        featureProjection: 'EPSG:28992', dataProjection: 'EPSG:28992' });
```

Comment: If you have a solution you should post it as an answer

Comment: Someone thought it was a similar question to another. But it wasn't at all. I wasn't able to put the solution elsewhere ... ;-( I will retry. Can you re-open the question?

Answer (score 1):

Loading the features: in this case from the 'assets' folder:

```
this.defineProjection();
this.httpClient.get('assets/wfs113-epsg-28992.xml', {responseType: 'text'})
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.fileText = data;
      var wfsFormat = new WFS({
        gmlFormat: new GML3()
      });
      this.gmlFeatures = wfsFormat.readFeatures(this.fileText, {
        featureProjection: 'EPSG:28992',
        dataProjection: 'EPSG:28992'
      });
      this.addGmlFeatures();
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
```

You have to define the specific projection first:

```
defineProjection() {
    proj4.defs("EPSG:28992", "+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000  +ellps=bessel  +towgs84=565.040,49.910,465.840,-0.40939,0.35971,-1.86849,4.0772 +units=m +no_defs");
    register(proj4)
    this.dutchProjection = GetProjection('EPSG:28992');
  }
```

The displaying of the features on the map:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    let polygonStyle = new Style({
      fill: new Fill({
        color: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8)"
      }),
      stroke: new Stroke({
        color: "#ffcc33",
        width: 10
      })
    });
    this.vectorSource = new VectorSource({
      format: new WFS(),
      features: []
    });
    this.vectorLayer = new Vector({
      source: this.vectorSource,
      style: [polygonStyle]
    });

    let scaleInfo = new ScaleLine({
      units: 'degrees',
      minWidth: 100
    });
    const mousePosition = new MousePosition({
      coordinateFormat: createStringXY(2),
      projection: 'EPSG:28992',
      undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;No coordinate active'
    });

    this.map = new Map({
      layers: [
        new Tile({
          source: new XYZ({
            url: 'https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/tiles/service/wmts/brtachtergrondkaart/EPSG:3857/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
          })
        }),
        this.vectorLayer
      ],
      view: new View({
        projection: this.dutchProjection,
        center: [173063,441818],
        zoom: 9
      }),
      target: "map"
    });
    this.map.addControl(scaleInfo);
    this.map.addControl(mousePosition);
    this.addGmlFeatures();
  }
```

And the adding of the features:

```
addGmlFeatures() {
    if (this.gmlFeatures.length > 0) {
      this.vectorLayer.getSource().addFeatures(this.gmlFeatures);
      //this.map.getView().fit( this.vectorSource.getExtent());
      console.log( this.map.getView().getProjection());
    }
  }
```

**Example file:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<wfs:FeatureCollection
  xmlns:ms="http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver"
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
  xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
  xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver http://atl-p0-app001.culture.fr:5522/cgi-bin/mapserv?SERVICE=WFS&amp;VERSION=1.1.0&amp;REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&amp;TYPENAME=MD_2775&amp;OUTPUTFORMAT=text/xml;%20subtype=gml/3.1.1  http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
  <gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:Envelope srsName="EPSG:28992">
      <gml:lowerCorner>173063 441818</gml:lowerCorner>
      <gml:upperCorner>173563 444318</gml:upperCorner>
    </gml:Envelope>
  </gml:boundedBy>
  <gml:featureMember>
    <ms:MD_2775>
      <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:Envelope srsName="EPSG:28992">
          <gml:lowerCorner>173063 441818</gml:lowerCorner>
          <gml:upperCorner>173563 444318</gml:upperCorner>
        </gml:Envelope>
      </gml:boundedBy>
      <ms:msGeometry>
        <gml:Polygon srsName="EPSG:28992">
          <gml:exterior>
            <gml:LinearRing>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="2">173063 441818 173463 441818 173463 444818 173063 444818 173063 441818 </gml:posList>
            </gml:LinearRing>
          </gml:exterior>
        </gml:Polygon>
      </ms:msGeometry>
      <ms:CODE></ms:CODE>
      <ms:LIBELLE></ms:LIBELLE>
      <ms:D_CREAT>19890303</ms:D_CREAT>
      <ms:ZONE>ZPPAUP</ms:ZONE>
      <ms:SURFACE>4.62397681219e+006</ms:SURFACE>
      <ms:COORD_X>6.70482028142e+005</ms:COORD_X>
      <ms:COORD_Y>7.09856001803e+006</ms:COORD_Y>
      <ms:INSEE>59309</ms:INSEE>
      <ms:COMMUNE>HONDSCHOOTE</ms:COMMUNE>
      <ms:DEPARTEMEN>NORD</ms:DEPARTEMEN>
      <ms:REGION>NORD-PAS-DE-CALAIS</ms:REGION>
    </ms:MD_2775>
  </gml:featureMember>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```